# replace first 20 occurances

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to capture (replace) first 20 occurrence of digits (before comma) in the following line

```
11112222333344445555, 123456
```

and insert comma between the digits. I tried adding `(\d)(\d) ... (\d)` 20 times and replacing by `\1,\2, ... \20` but it failed. May I know a better way of doing it using notepad++.

Comment: What do you mean "it failed"?  Given what you've posted, that should work.  That leads me to think there's something misrepresented or that you haven't posted.

Comment: @Travis it seems that notepad++ does not support replace `\10` and beyond it. It is same as `\1` + `0`.

Comment: Interesting.  (I don't have Notepad++ myself).  Why don't you just run two regexes then?  (the second would probably have to be different to account for the modifications after the first)

Comment: +1, notepad++ is based on boost, and if I'm quoting [the good documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) it specifies that it only handles backreferences up to `\9`

Comment: Unless Notepad++ limits the number of named backreferences as well, you could use named backreferences after the first nine to get to your total of 20

Comment: @Travis is there a way to do it? I know I can always do it using any language but just want to know if I can do it using notepad++ or not.

Comment: I'm testing out a solution right now.  I'll post once I've verified it.

Comment: I tried using the `\g{11}` syntax described in the doc I linked above but it didn't work :-/ That's strange, because it's also described in notepad++'s [official doc](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @SantoshLinkha See my answer.  It works in PCRE mode (what Notepad++ uses) on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/), but you need to check if Notepad++ will actually accept it.

Comment: I thought [`(?<!.{20})\d\B\K`](https://www.regex101.com/r/O7IRjd/1) and replace by `,` would be  a nice idea but unfortunately does not seem to work in np++. But if your string always exactly looks like `digits, digits` and you want to match before any `,` could replace [`\d\B\K(?=[^,]+,)` by `,`](https://www.regex101.com/r/O7IRjd/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution which doesn't require naming the groups :

- search for `(\d)(\d)...(\d)`
- replace by `$1, $2, ... $9, $10, ... $20`

You can enclose the backreference number in curly brackets if it helps disambiguate the expression : `$11` and `${11}` both refers to the 11th expression, while `${1}1` refers to the 1st backreference followed by the character `1`.

The syntax is described in [Notepad++'s documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Substitutions), but careful not to try to use the search syntax (`\g{n}`) in the replace field !

Comment: it seems, you don't need to wrap around `{}`

Comment: @SantoshLinkha right, I've edited this in. Notepad++'s documentation on the subject really is lackluster :-/

Answer (score 3):

**Find:**

```
(?<a>\d)(?<b>\d)(?<c>\d)(?<d>\d)(?<e>\d)(?<f>\d)(?<g>\d)(?<h>\d)(?<i>\d)(?<j>\d)(?<k>\d)(?<l>\d)(?<m>\d)(?<n>\d)(?<o>\d)(?<p>\d)(?<q>\d)(?<r>\d)(?<s>\d)(?<t>\d)
```

**Replace:**

```
${a},${b},${c},${d},${e},${f},${g},${h},${i},${j},${k},${l},${m},${n},${o},${p},${q},${r},${s},${t}
```

[proof of concept](https://regex101.com/r/pGzs0O/1)

---

Now all this being said... for similar problems with larger `n`, you're probably better off using an iterative / programmatic approach (using the language of your choice) rather than a single-shot "find/replace" regex operation.

Example in Java:

```
String input = /* some string */;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
String match = matcher.group();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(match.length()*2);
for (char ch : match.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append(ch);
    sb.append(',');
}
String replacement = sb.substring(0,sb.length()-1);

String result = replacement + input.subString(match.length());
```

Answer (score 2):

For capture group with number greater than 9, you should use `${10}` `${11}` ...

-Find what: `(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)`
-Replace with: `$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,${10},${11},${12},${13},${14},${15},${16},${17},${18},${19},${20}`

But it is unmaintable for greater number, I'd suggest you to use:

- Find what: `(?<![ \d])\d(?!,)`
- Replace with: `$0,`